# T-SQL - How can I get data in a row to show in a column

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, pivot

I have a record set that contains course attendance data in a row that I want to display in columns based on the last letter in the Course_Code and haven't been able to find a method for this.

The Course_Code filed contains the city followed by a sequence letter denoting the order the modules are to be taken. A must be first followed by B, then C etc.

The data looks like this:

```
Course_Code  Student_ID
MadridA      123
ParisB       123
NewYorkC     123
HamburgD     123
HamburgA     456
ParisB       456
HamburgC     456
HamburgD     456
HamburgA     789
ParisB       789
HamburgC     789
MadridD      789
```

What I need the result to look like is:

```
Student_ID CourseA  CourseB  CourseC  CourseD
123        MadridA  ParisB   NewYorkC HamburgD
456        HamburgA ParisB   HamburgC HamburgD
789        HamburgA ParisB   HamburgC MadridD
```

I've been looking into PIVOT as a likely solution but can't find any example that doesn't involve SUM or AVG on data values. I don't need to change the data just move to the appropriate column.

Is PIVOT going to do what I need or am I in the wrong creek with a broken paddle on that?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the PIVOT function to get the result, but you will need to use either the `max` or `min` aggregate function since your data is a string.

You should be able to use the following:

```
select student_id,
  CourseA, CourseB, 
  CourseC, CourseD
from
(
  select course_code, student_id,
    -- append the course letter A, etc to Course to get the new column names
    col = 'Course'+right(course_code, 1)  
  from yourtable
) d
pivot
(
  max(course_code)
  for col in (CourseA, CourseB, CourseC, CourseD)
) piv;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/50b8e/3)

Comment: Bluefeet, based on the diamond next to your name, I take it the election went well? :)

Comment: @christiandev Yes, I was elected yesterday :)

Comment: Congrats, you got my vote anyway....surprised to see you answer a `Pivot` question here :)

Comment: @christiandev I love pivot questions.

Comment: @bluefeet - just wow! that sure looks like what I need. I'll some validation to confirm I'm getting the right values.

Comment: @bluefeet - I've checked and double-checked your [tag:PIVOT] answer. Works perfectly. Thanks you. I'm still new to upvote this - not enough  rep points.